# Jqgrid delete events not triggering after JSON parse

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm loading Jqgrid col headers and colModel dynamically from Server (C#).  I want to edit/delete the rows and hence I'm adding the "actions" colModel at the end . But the "actions" colModel is JSON parsed to be added to the list coming from Server. The issue is ,my delete events like "OnclickSubmit" is not getting triggered . However the  properties of delOptions like delData and url are working. Any suggestion on how to trigger the events ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: { selectedDate: dateValue, filterCriteria: criteria },
    url: '/Allocation/GetAllocationGridHeaders',
    success: function (data) {
        col_names = data.ColHeaders;
        var colEditModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
            name: "actions",
            width: 50,
            formatter: "actions",
            sortable: false,
            search: false,
            formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                editOptions: {},
                addOptions: {},
                delOptions: {
                    url: "Allocation/DummyURL",                //Working
                    delData: { ResourceID: 5, TaskID: 5 },     //Working

                    onclickSubmit: function(options) {         // Not triggered
                        options.url = "Allocation/DeleteAllocation";
                    },
                }
            }
        }));

        data.ColModel.push(colEditModel);
        col_model = data.ColModel,
        $.jgrid.gridUnload("#jqGrid");

 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
      url: "Allocation/GetAllocations",
      mtype: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      colModel: col_model,
      colNames: col_names,
      editurl: "Allocation/EditAllocation",
      loadonce: true,
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
            });
```

Comment: Which sense is in the usage of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({name: "actions",...}))`? Why you not use just `{name: "actions",...}`?

Comment: I'm new to js mate. Removed parse and stringify function. It works. Thanks a ton ! :)

Comment: You are welcome! I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.2. It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop. It's compatible to old jqGrid (<=4.7), but contains many enhancements. For example there are many predefined templates which simplifies the code. For example you can use `{name: "actions", template: "actions"}`, you can define custom action buttons. You can specify editing options on top level of jqGrid. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). There are many other features.

Comment: Sure mate. Sounds nice.  Will look into it :)

Comment: @Oleg In the snippet above, the events for delete works. But I don' t know how to add eventhandlers for Edit. I'm using inline edit with row control buttons. I included the eventhandlers in editOptions. But it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Comment: If you use old jqGrid then you have to specify inline edit callback under the names described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). For example `afterSave` instead of [aftersavefunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). Did you read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods), which I reference before? Free jqGrid allows to use `inlineEditing` option of jqGrid to configure of any options/callbacks on inline editing.

Comment: [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) is an example of relatively complex combination of inline and form editing and `formatter: "actions"` and local filtering of the data. You can examine its source code very easy. It has `inlineEditing: {keys: true}` which can be extended with any other inline editing options or callbacks. In the same way `formEditing`, `formDeleting` and `searching` can be used to specify form editing and searching options. One have one place for any direct or indirect (by `navGrid` or `formatter: "actions"`) editing.

Comment: @Oleg I referred to one of your previous solutions and used `serializeRowData` event  to get my desired result. Thanks a lot for your time :)